# Serializable and NonSerializable

Tags: c#

[Serializable]
or 
[NonSerializable], Whats the difference?

for example:

`[Serializable]
public class Motorcycle
{
}`

`[NonSerializable]
public class Motorcycle
{
}`

I really don't understand the difference can anyone point me to a source of explanation.

There are explanations online but I feel I don't understand such a high level technical explanation.

Comment: "A method [...] can be `[Serializable]` or `[NonSerializable]`. Wrong. Only types can be marked with `[Serializable]` and only fields can be marked with `[NonSerialized]`.

Comment: `NonSerializableAttribute` is not exist, it should be `NonSerializedAttribute` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: One phrase in google "programming serialization" :[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

Comment: NB: `NonSerializedAttribute` is only used in a field due to `AttributeTargets.Field` in effect, it can't be used to mark class-level as non serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine an object, like a Motorcycle being able to be saved with State. As in saved in a state with the variables set, eg properties Color=black, Brand=Harley Davidson... and with the Serialization attribute you can save that object with its variables set.. Serializable means it's state can be saved along with the type.

Non-Serialized attributes do the opposite they exclude variables being saved.

You should try it out to see what I mean. I can't explain it any simpler (high-level) than this. All the stuff you are reading must be low-level implementation details.